# Saving And Loading CollapsiblePanelExtender Control State Over Postback

Tags: updatepanel, controls, state, collapsiblepanelextender

I'm using asp.net/c# and have a number of Collapsible Panel Extenders that have been dynamically created when the page loads. The controls are within an update panel that updates every 5 seconds. The problem I have is whenever the update panel updates the state of the controls is reset. For example the Collapsible Panel Extender start life as collapsed, if I then expand the panel and an update occurs the panel is set back to collapsed.

How can I save the state of the Collapsible Panel Extenders and then reload the state once the update has occurred? Is this even the correct way to to it?

Thanks

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, all you need to do is add the controls during page initialization rather than page load. They then retain there state.